# Не присваивается значение переменной типа AnsiString

Tags: c++, строки

Вот код

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
AnsiString str111 = "string";
}
```

Выдает вот это:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrAsg(System::AnsiStringT<0>&, const System::AnsiStringT<0>)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrCat(System::AnsiStringT<0>&, const System::AnsiStringT<0>)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrCat3(System::AnsiStringT<0>&, const System::AnsiStringT<0>, const System::AnsiStringT<0>)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrClr(void *)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrCmp()' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrDelete(System::AnsiStringT<0>&, int, int)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrFromArray(System::AnsiStringT<0>&, char *, int, unsigned short)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrFromPChar(System::AnsiStringT<0>&, char *, unsigned short)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrFromUStr(System::AnsiStringT<0>&, const System::UnicodeString, unsigned short)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrFromWChar(System::AnsiStringT<0>&, wchar_t, unsigned short)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrFromWStr(System::AnsiStringT<0>&, const System::WideString, unsigned short)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrInsert(const System::AnsiStringT<0>, System::AnsiStringT<0>&, int)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrSetLength(System::AnsiStringT<0>&, int, unsigned short)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall LStrFromPWCharLen(System::AnsiStringT<0>&, wchar_t *, int, unsigned short)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall CheckAutoResult(long)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall DynArrayRelease(void *)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall DynArrayAddRef(void *)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::InstanceSize()' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::InitInstance(void *)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::ClassName()' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::ClassParent()' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::ClassInfo()' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::InheritsFrom(System::TMetaClass *)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::MethodName(void *)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::QualifiedClassName()' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::UnitName()' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::UnitScope()' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::MethodAddress(System::SmallString<255>&)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::GetInterfaceEntry(_GUID&)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::GetInterfaceTable()' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::ClassNameIs(const System::UnicodeString)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::MethodAddress(const System::UnicodeString)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::__linkproc__ __fastcall FindDynaInst(const System::TObject * const, short)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\11.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|System_thunks_win32
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:00.4
```

Не могу понять в чем дело. Просветите пожалуйста. Буду очень благодарен.

**Дополнительно**

Все что тут написано выдает те же ошибки http://www.sources.ru/builder/faq/007.html

Answer (score 1):

Нужно вот так:

```
AnsiString str111 = 1;
```

т.е. кавычки не нужны

почитайте еще http://www.sources.ru/builder/faq/007.html

Comment: Я дописал свое сообщение. Все те же ошибки.